# Javascript click event in outlook 2007

Tags: javascript, html

We have Toggele image (Plus-Minus) on Div. Plus should expand div and minus should collepse div. Will it work when i send html email to outlook having this div and Toggle as Javascript function called from image click?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is generally not supported by E-Mail clients.

Comment: is there any other way i can achieve this with outlook email client?

Comment: @jatin I don't think so, no. I would consider linking to a HTML page where stuff like this can be done easily

Comment: Thanks. That's what i thought initially.